# Blank page when navigating to http://localhost:3000/say/hello

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and am doing my first tutorial and am running the latest version of rails 3 and ruby 1.9.2.  After creating my controller and navigating to http://localhost:3000/say/hello I'm receiving a blank page. I do see the Welcome to Rails message when I just go to http://localhost:3000. I've done some Google searches and people have similar problems but there is no clear fix. I've never really worked with MVC before so the concept of routing is fairly new to  me.

Below is my controller:

```
class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
  end
  def goodbye
  end
end
```

My view:

```
<h1>Say hello to Rails!</h1>
```

Comment: have you set a route to the say controller?

Answer (score 3):

You should delete the public/index.html file as that will mess with your routing and display by default. Have you set up your routes already, and what is the exact location and filename of the template?

You will need something like in your config/routes.rb file to correctly route that url to your template/view:

```
match '/say/hello' => 'say#hello'
```

Comment: Ok, I deleted the public/index.html file which got me a little closer. My config/routes.rb file is displayed below. Do I have to set up the routes? I thought that was already done for me, my tutorial wasn't clear.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not seeing any route file, did you forget to include it perhaps? :-)

Answer (score 1):

First delete the index.html file from your public folder. Then, go to the app/views and check the views for the say controller. You should have a hello.html.erb.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your particular question was answered already by Bitterzoet, but I thought you might want some alternative learning resources.

I'm not sure which tutorial you're starting with, but I find it odd that they're not using RESTful routes. You can find out what routes you have set up at the moment by going to the console and typing "rake routes". If you would like a different tutorial, I recommend the one here: 
http://www.wiki.devchix.com/index.php?title=Rails_3_Curriculum

I'd also recommend http://railsforzombies.org/ as a good first-time rails experience.

Answer (score 1):

A fun general line to add to config/routes is:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

While developing, this will allow you to display the controller/action in address bar for ALL controller/action/id.format etc.

Like Bitterzote wrote, if controller is "say" and action is "hello", http://localhost:3000/say/hello .
If you use controller "say" and action "move", http://localhost:3000/say/move .

I've found this route to be very useful during development, but change this if you launch your application! (Rails warns: "Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.")